# How to force SVG to scale down to parent container

Tags: svg

By setting the `viewbox` attribute on my SVG and removing `width` I can force an SVG to fit to the size of it's container:

```
<div id="chart">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

This works great when the page first loads and it also means I can easily size the SVG using CSS on the container element:

```
#chart {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When I increase the size of the browser the SVG scales up. Unfortunately the same is not true when I reduce the size of the browser. How can I ensure that the SVG also *shrinks* to fit?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr6Vw/1/)

Comment: Seems OK to me on Firefox. What UA are you using?

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome & IE 11 - which browser are you seeing this behaviour?

Comment: I was running Chrome Canary - looks like there are a few issues relating to SVG rendering in the latest build. Switched to Chrome stable and all is well. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @BenFoster looks fine to me in Chrome 38.0.2121.3 dev, which exact version did you have trouble with?